# Select User By Name and all related entities in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have

```
Users(Id, Name)
UserClaims(Id, UserId, Type, Value)
UserLogins(ProviderName, ProviderKey, UserId)
UserRoles(UserId, RoleId)
Roles(Id, Name)
```

How can I select a user with all related entity by name in a single query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: One would think that a user with 3k+ rep would know how to properly format questions...

Comment: I need a select query where name = @name but join all the related entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to join the related tables, and if so maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN UserClaims UC ON U.Id = UC.UserId
INNER JOIN UserLogins UL ON U.Id = UL.UserId
INNER JOIN UserRoles UR ON U.Id = UR.UserId
INNER JOIN Roles R ON R.Id = UR.RoleId
WHERE U.Name = 'name' -- or @name or whatever way you pass the variable...
```

Comment: This is good, if all the related tables has at least one record per user. If this is not true, use LEFT JOIN insted where it is necessary.

Comment: @Pred Indeed. The query should be easy to adjust to LEFT JOINs where appropriate though.